# Calculate dropwdown list prices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Forgive me if I am way off the mark in terms of the naming things correctly.

I have a multiple dropdown lists calculating prices after each selection is picked, at the end of all the lists i have a total amount that's been added up each time, but I want the last dropdown list to discount the total amount by a % not add to it.

The prices come from mysql and so will the discount, here's the code i use to get  the prices

```
$(function(){
    $(".calculate").on("change", function(){
        var total = 0;
        $('.calculate').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() != 0) {
                total += parseFloat($(this).val());
            }
        });
        $('#total').text('£' + total.toFixed(2));
    });

});//]]>
```

I thought it would be something to do with `total += parseFloat($(this).val());`. I thought by replacing `+` with `/` it would work but nothing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'd remove the `calculate` class from the `<select>` that is going to do the **discount**, and assign it an `id="discount"`, here's an example of the `<select>`:

```
<select id="discount" name="select-3">
    <option value="0">Select Discount Amount</option>
    <option value="10%">10%</option>
    <option value="20%">20%</option>
    <option value="50%">50%</option>
</select>
```

Then when either the `#discount`, or any of the `.calculate` elements are changed, first loop and add the totals of all elements with the class `calculate`, before applying the discount, like so:

```
$(function(){
    $(".calculate, #discount").on("change", function(){
        var total = 0;
        $('.calculate').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() != 0) {
                total += parseFloat($(this).val());
            }
        });
        if($('#discount').val() != 0) {
          total = total * ((100 - parseFloat($('#discount').val())) / 100);
        }
        $('#total').text('£' + total.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qCjM2/)

Comment: Once again deifwud, you've done it again, it's working perfect, just 2 more parts and it's finished.

Comment: Hi deifwud, i'm not sure if you've seen my new question, but after your help with my last 2 questions i'm hopping you can finish it off. I want to add a vat amount and a combined total amount (total + VAT =) also, at the moment if i have a multiple selection list, it won't change the price if i select 2 or more. Once i have those 2 parts i'm finished other than trying to find a nice looking dropdown list with checkboxes (for those multiple selections, Impossible to find)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
$(function(){
   $(".calculate").on("change", function(){
       var total = 0;
       var discount_amount = define_value;
       $('.calculate').each(function() {
           if($(this).val() != 0) {
               discount_amount = $(this).val() * discount_variable;
               line_total = $(this).val() - discount_amount;
               total += parseFloat(line_total);
           }
       });
       $('#total').text('£' + total.toFixed(2));
});

});//]]>
```